# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined google sheets app scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have code where I'm trying to index and pull data from a previous sheet.  This code used to work, but now i'm getting a `typeError` when running the code.

```
function updateLocations(market) {   
   

  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lastPeriod = activeSheet.getSheetByName("Update Info").getRange("C7").getValue();
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(lastPeriod).getSheetByName("Assembly Redwood");
  var targetSheet = activeSheet.getSheetByName("Assembly Redwood");


  var targetArr = targetSheet.getRange(4,1,targetSheet.getLastRow(),10).getValues();
  var sourceArr = sourceSheet.getRange(4,1,sourceSheet.getLastRow(),10).getValues();

  var POlistTarget = targetArr.map(function(r){return [r[0],r[1]]});
  var POlistSource = sourceArr.map(function(r){return [r[0],r[1]]});

  var skuList = POlistTarget.map(function(r){return [r[1]]});



  var arrSource = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < POlistSource.length; i++){
    var POSKU = POlistSource[i][0]+POlistSource[i][1];
    arrSource.push(POSKU);
  }

  var arrTarget = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < POlistTarget.length; i++){
    var POSKU = POlistTarget[i][0]+POlistTarget[i][1];
    arrTarget.push(POSKU);
  }



  var units = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arrTarget.length; i++){
    var row = arrSource.indexOf(arrTarget[i]);
    var unit = sourceArr[row][8]; //***************type error flags this line
    units.push([unit]);
  }
Logger.log(units);


}
```

All of the variables seem to be logging correctly, but I'm still getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '8' of undefined (line 333, file
> "Code")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Issue:**

[Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

Based on the error you are getting I assume that this returns `-1`:

```
var row = arrSource.indexOf(arrTarget[i]) // value of row is -1
```

and therefore `sourceArr[-1]` undefined and these is why you can't use:

```
var unit = sourceArr[row][8]
```

because you are asking for the 8th element of something **undefined** `sourceArr[-1]`.

### Solution:

Check first if you get a non-negative value from the `indexOf` method:

```
  var units = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arrTarget.length; i++){
    var row = arrSource.indexOf(arrTarget[i]);
    console.log(row) // console row to see its value
    if (row>-1){
      var unit = sourceArr[row][8]; 
      units.push([unit]);
    }
  }
```

or `if (row!=-1)` works as well.

### Minimal Reproducible Example:

```js
  const sourceArr = [[3,1,4,30,32,12,1,4,5,3],
                     [3,1,4,30,32,12,1,4,5,3],
                     [3,1,4,30,32,12,1,4,5,3],
                     [3,1,4,30,32,12,1,4,5,3]]
  
console.log(sourceArr[0][8]); // this works
console.log(sourceArr[-1][8]); // TypeError: Cannot read property '8' of undefined
```